# Change Event to Hide Textbox and Label

Tags: excel, vba

I have a ListBox with MultiSelect and Change Event. The End User selects a option and it dynamically creates a textbox and label adjacent to it. The change event associated with the condition fires once due to the boolean flag being Static. The issue is when the user unchecks the option. I have a condition that checks if the event was already fired and then it hides the textbox and label. The error is

> "Object variable or With Block variable not set"

when attempting to set the visible field of the textbox and label False.

Below is the code.

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Change()

Static Case1 As Boolean 'interface Scheduling Change
Static Case2 As Boolean 'generation bottling
Static Case3 As Boolean 'Area Max Reserve

Dim txtB1 As Control
Dim txtB1_label As Control


If ListBox1.Selected(0) And Not Case1 Then  'Trigger Event when Option(0) Selected (ensures event triggers only once)
    Set txtB1 = Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1")
    Set txtB1_label = Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1")
    With txtB1_label
        .Caption = "MW (TTC)"
        .Left = 162
        .Top = 120
        .Width = 42
        .Visible = True

    End With
    With txtB1
        .Name = "demo"
        .Height = 15
        .Width = 48
        .Left = 204
        .Top = 120
    End With
    Case1 = True
End If

If Not ListBox1.Selected(0) And Case1 Then  'Resets Trigger if Option(0) is unSelected
    MsgBox "No Nice"
    txtB1_label.Visible = False
    txtB1.Visible = False

    Case1 = False
End If

End Sub
```

Is there an issue with the logic?

Edit:
So essentially, I click the first option ListBox1.Selected(0), it triggers the first If...Else Block and creates the textbox and label. It then sets Case1 Flag to True. Then I Unclick the first option. The Second If...Else Block checks that it is unclicked and that Case1 is True meaning that it was clicked previously. This works because the code enters the block and I see the MsgBox. At this point, the textbox and Label are still existent . I don't understand why it's not set. I instantiated it in the first if...else block.

Thanks

Comment: At what line the error appears?

Comment: If the first condition is never met (the first If...End If), then `Set txtB1_label = Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1")` never occurs.

Comment: @FaneDuru In the second If Block when setting the visible field of txtB1_label to False.

Comment: @BigBen It is met. I checked by creating that MsgBox to see if it enters the block.  I set Case1 to True in the first If block . The second If block then executes when Case1 is True. So it occurs after the textbox and label are created.

Comment: From the error message - the only explanation is that that the object is not set.

Comment: @BigBen When Change events are refired, does the Object that is instantiated goes away? If so, then this is the reason. Static Variables maintain their status which explains why the if...else block is still executing.